# テキストボックスからフォーカスがはずれません

Tags: c#, wpf

テキストボックス以外のスペースをクリックしたら、テキストボックスからフォーカスがはずれるようにしたいのですが、この場合ウインドウのクリックイベント時に、Focus()でウインドウにフォーカスを合わせる方法しかないのでしょうか？

textboxにフォーカスが合って以後、他のtextboxやbuttonをクリックするまでフォーカスが移動しません。 （FocusableがTrueの空きスペースをクリックしても、textboxからフォーカスがはずれません）

他の方法が分かる方がいましたらご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

クリックした場所にある `UIElement` の `Focusable` が `True` になっていればフォーカス移動すると思います。

Comment: 設定してあるのですが、textboxにフォーカスが合って以後、他のtextboxやbuttonをクリックするまでフォーカスが移動しません。
（空きスペースをクリックしても、textboxからフォーカスがはずれません）
返答ありがとうございます。

Comment: Backgroundも指定してありますか？

Comment: 指定していませんでしたので、指定して実装してみます。
ご返答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決することが出来ました、ありがとうございます